# Any way I can call destructor function do destroy an object? c++/smfl

Tags: c++, class, sfml, destructor

In SFML I am trying to amke a game and I made a Bullet class where I put a destrucor function. I want to destroy the bullet when pressing a button, but when I pressed it, my window freezed and pc kina crashed. Is there any way to destroy the object? I allready tried not to draw it, but it is still there, just invisible.

`if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::E)) bullet1.~Bullets();`
[the error after the program crashes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqjWt.png)

Comment: There is almost never a good reason to call a destructor manually. The best approach would be to put `bullet1` into some kind of container that it can be removed from, such as a `std::vector` or `std::optional`. What work does `Bullet` do when it is destroyed?

Comment: Provide some [mre] in your question, and take more time to read about C++ and about SFML

Comment: Note that if you're just starting to learn C++, SFML is explicitly not a great library to be using. It assumes you're familiar with many advanced and nuanced C++ features and it won't help you if you screw something up. From the [SFML FAQ](https://www.sfml-dev.org/faq.php#grl-learn): `"don't start with SFML if you are trying to grasp the basic language features of C++"`

Comment: `bullet1.~Bullets();` This leaves the object uninitialized, and any attempt to use it will result in undefined behavior. It is rare that an explicit destructor call is a good idea, but if you *must* do it, then at least leave the object in a consistent state, for example call the placement new `new(&bullet1) Bullets();` right after the destructor in order to reinitialize the object.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a destructor explicitly, but you can get the same behavior having the bullet in a pointer and calling `delete` on it. Just be sure to make always a `new` before any `delete`, and a `delete` for every `new`.

```cpp
// When declaring your variables
Bullets* bullet1 = nullptr; // don't call delete in this state
...

// In your bullet creation code
bullet1 = new Bullets();
...

// Delete the object and put pointer to null
delete bullet1; // Destructor will be called here
bullet1 = nullptr;

// When drawing it you must check if the object exists
if(bullet1 != nullptr){
  window.draw(bullet1);
}
```

Anyways, as said in the comments, **you shouldn't start with SFML until you have a good understanding of C++ basics and OOP**.